# Java Ternary Operator insert != null check and syso not printed

Tags: java, operator-keyword, ternary

I have two questions.
First

```
int i = 0;
System.out.println("\nint i is" + (i == 0) ? "i==0" : "i!=0");
```

I receive this error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to boolean
Eclipse tells me
1 quick fix available:
Insert != null check

Second

```
System.out.println("\nint i is" + (i == 0) != null ? "i==0" : "i!=0");
```

With the != null check I get no error, but "\nint i is" is not printed, only the result i==0. I totally not understand the errors. Please help =)

Comment: [Operator precedence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parenthesize your conditional expression properly:

```
System.out.println("\nint i is" + ((i == 0) ? "i==0" : "i!=0"));
```

Otherwise, `+` is executed before applying the conditional, so the conditional is parsed as follows:

```
"\nint i is" + (i == 0) ? "i==0" : "i!=0"
-----------------------   ------   ------
             |              |         |
Condition ---+              |         |
When the condition is true -+         |
When the condition is false ----------+
```

`"\nint i is" + (i == 0)` is a valid Java expression that produces a string, triggering the "need a Boolean" error.